# AngularJs with routes and anchor tags, working on second click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a simple view representing a simple menu which should be using `anchor` behavior. On the same page there's a bunch of `H2` tags with `id` that the links should scroll to.

I'm using the `$anchorScroll` and `$location`.

**THE ISSUE:** The first time I click a link, I can see that the route is updated, e.g.:

`http://localhost:60002/#!/docs/view/somedoc#someResourceId`

But **it triggers a route**, the **SECOND time** I click it, it behaves as expected.

**UPDATE:** It's not the `anchorScroll()` did it manually using `element.scrollIntoView(true)` same behavior. If I don't use `$location.hash` it works, but then I loose the possibility of linking to anchors.

Any ideas?

**VIEW:**

```
<div ng-controller="DocsMenuCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems">
        <li><a ng-click="foo(menuItem.resourceId)">{{menuItem.title}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
...
...
<h2 id="...">Test</h2>
...
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
module.controller('DocsMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$anchorScroll', 'session', function ($scope, $http, $location, $anchorScroll, session) {
    $scope.foo = function (resourceId) {
        $location.hash(resourceId);

        $anchorScroll();
    };

    $http.get('/api/menu/').success(function (d) {
        $scope.menuItems = d;
    }).error(function () {
        session.logger.log(arguments);
    });
}]);
```

**ROUTEPROVIDER CONFIG etc**

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

$routeProvider
    .when('/default', {
        templateUrl: 'clientviews/default',
        controller: 'DefaultCtrl'
    })
    .when('/docs/view/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'clientviews/docs',
        controller: 'DocsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/default'
    });
```

Comment: What does your $.routeProvider look like?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS edited with requested info.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: Yes. But I do not remember what the issue was. Are U having similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

`$location` does not reload the page even if it is used to change the url. See the "What does it not do?" section of this page: [$location ngDoc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/%24location).

Comment: Where do I say it reloads?

Answer (score 0):

As Ganonside said, the location service does not reload the url. Once you are certain that the url changes you can use the route service, specifically $route.reload() to trigger your routing.

Comment: I don't want a reload or route to be triggered. That is the issue. It should scroll to a anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is here:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1699#issuecomment-22509845

Another option, if you don't use search params, is to tell the route provider not to reload on hash or search changes (unfortunately, it is one option for both).

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/group/:groupName', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/groupView.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```